# Drush failing to load drush.php file

Tags: 8, drush

I have Drupal 8 project on my local machine, which is set up with composer and I got drush included. When I'm in project root I can call drush like:

```
vendor/bin/drush -v
```

And that work well (initialized it so I can call it without typing full path):

```
Drush Commandline Tool 9.7.2
```

...

But when I moved the same project to staging server, when I try to run the same command I get error message:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/path_to_project/vendor/bin/drush.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path_to_project/vendor/bin/drush on line 4
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/path_to_project/vendor/bin/drush.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /path_to_project/vendor/bin/drush on line 4
```

Inside drush file I'm executing from bin there is only one line (line 4):

```
require __DIR__ . '/drush.php';
```

But that require fails and triggers this error. drush.php file is located (in both cases) inside: `vendor/drush/drush/drush.php`

I have another project with the same setup and drush there works well on local box and on that other staging server, so I know problem is in server setup somewhere, but don't know where exactly? That include path from error message "`include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear'`" looks suspicious to me.

Since I'm not server admin do I need his help to solve this?

Comment: I guess there is a broken symlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what @remy said is true.

Inside /vendor/bin all "files" are actually symlinks. Real files are located elsewhere. However when copying those files (i.e. with Filezilla) instead of copying symlinks original files were copied.
I solved this by zipping whole bin dir, copying archive and unzipping in on remote server.

Zipping it with mac finder keeps sym links well. However, when zipping form command line most likely option --symlinks should be set:

```
zip --symlinks -r foo.zip foo/
```

https://serverfault.com/questions/265675/how-can-i-zip-compress-a-symlink

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @MilanG that the symlinks is missing.

So, to fix this you will need to remove the `vendor` folder and installing the packages from composer again.

1. `rm -rf ./vendor`
2. `composer install`